# How do i see this special character in C#/.NET winform?

Tags: .net, winforms

There is a special character which can be seen here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm

I have the correct font for it, i can even copy/paste it in firefox. I can see the text in firefox without using an image. But when i paste it into winforms i do not. I see two boxes with `?` inside of each. Its one letter. Oddly enough i can copy the text out and paste it into firefox and see it correctly. (Note i made sure to copy/paste regular text in firefox to ensure i am not repasting what i originally copied).

I'm setting the font like so `textBox3.Font = new Font("symbola", 12);` symbola has the font required to view that special character. In fact before i downloaded it and right click install on the ttf file firefox didnt show the character correctly. I have restarted my computer since.

How do i get winform to display the character properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using a `RichTextBox`. I have had intermittent trouble using Unicode on the regular `TextBox`, even with all fonts installed correctly. It nearly always works when you set it from code, but there are sometimes problems with interactivity. At any rate, I never know the cause of it, but `RichTextBox` has typically worked in these situations.

Comment: Ok i tried it. still no luck (see my comment in serge answer)

Comment: @acidzombie24 Yep, this works on my end too. I got the font from the same place you did. It works in both RichTextBox and TextBox, both by setting it manually like Serge's example and through copy/paste. I have heard of some UTF fonts rendering weirdly due to "locale" settings, but I think it'd be doing it system-wide if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks for the email. It doesnt display properly! I checked my locale and its english united states. I dont... understand. What is wrong with my system! at least... i programmed it right? anyways thanks and accepted!

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Font = new Font("symbola", 16); 
  button1.Text = "\U0001F4A9";
}
```

2 remarks:

- The character is not in the BMP: It can't be represented using a single 16 bits word. In UTF16 parlance, it's a surrogate pair. Note the special encoding required in the source code above. Also, this representation doesn't work in WinForms designer properties. I had to assign the text in the class' code file.
- I also couldn't assign the font in the WinForms designer properties: It complains that the font is not True Type, which it seems to be. Again, assigning the font in the code worked.

FWIW, my test was done using VS2008 and .NET 3.5 under Win7 x64

EDIT: I also tested it under VS2010 / .NET 4 and .NET 3.5: Works like a charm

Comment: Really? I am using visual studios 2010 and .NET 3.5 and that DOESNT work. I tried buttons and textbox. I did it in code like your example shows. I am using Win7 64bits. I wonder if someone can confirm the above working and the OS they are on

Comment: argh, i tried it in 2010 as well and it didnt work. Where did you get the font file? I got mine here http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/ what OS are you using? i dont suppose you want to email me the binary to see if it works on my machine? (my email is in my profile)

Comment: Argh, you are on .NET 3.5. OK, VS2010 / .NET3.5 / Win7 x64 works for me. I'll mail you the exe. And yers, I got the font from there as well