# Why does my system not display unicode correctly?

Tags: unicode

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021615) and it turns out the code **is** correct but it doesnt display properly on my system. I dont understand! why might it do this? My system is set to united states english. I dont know what the problem can be.

This makes it difficult to develop unicode apps when it doesn't display properly on my system :(

-Edit- To be more clear. I made a winform app using .NET and the text appears incorrect on my machine but works on others. I can copy/paste text into my app but i wont know if it ran correctly since i see nonsense instead of text. However most unicode works. Special chars (like >16bits) does not.

Comment: @Jan: Win7 64bit. Same as the other persons machine

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the question you linked to that you are on a windows machine. The problem could be that windows does not have a global encoding option at all. The united states english is a *language setting* which as far as I know does not mean what you expect it to mean, as in it does not set all of your programs to show text in a unicode format.

The quick answer is that especially in windows, each program that displays text to the user is responsible for the character encoding. You have to make sure that the program and the environment where the problem appears are set to display text using some unicode format, such as **UTF-8**.

Read up on [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks, now i happen to be using .NET 3.5 (and 4) and the other person is using the same font and system as me (win7 64bits). It works on his and not mine. I am using regular text files and rich text. He actually send me his code and all i had to do was run the prj. It works for him and not for me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Set the text encoding in your IDE to UTF-8 and it should work. You can usually find this setting in the same place where you'd choose your editors font and font size.